# Ad infinitum scrolling for questions, like Google Reader

Tags: feature-request, questions, user-interface

When I read a subscription on Google Reader, Google just-in-time loads more entries as I reach the bottom of the page. It would be nice to have the SO sites do this too instead of having a pager on questions with lots of answers.

Comment: I strongly dislike this behavior of Google Reader.

Comment: It could be an option in the account prefs... Those who like it turn it on, others leave it alone.

Comment: Not sure how Read does it, but Google Images has little labels where the page breaks would normally be

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay, but first you have to install Firefox and Greasemonkey.

Then click here - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8472/script-infinite-scrolling-of-answers

And finally, if you're a programmer versed in jQuery/javascript, please help improve the functionality a bit.

Comment: I also had a greasemonkey script for this... I've added my version as an answer to your linked question.

Comment: That's *exactly* what I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: I added an answer to your question.

Comment: Is there something similar for Questions? Ah and the link is dead (deleted)

Answer (score 7):

I don't particularly care about this for questions, but it'd be great for *answers*... So long as they don't pull a UserVoice and break linking with crappy AJAX.

Comment: Sorry about that, that's what I meant. Instead of putting the pager at the bottom of the question page, it would autoload more answers to the question.

Answer (score 7):

Pagination is in my opinion much better then progressive loading.  Progressive loading breaks both the scrollbar and the back button.

The problem with pagination is that it breaks the browser's Find function; however, progressive loading does not fix this issue either.  (We'd need a "view all" or "print view" option.)

Answer (score 6):

For SO, I actually prefer paging. Other sites like DZone use this auto-scrolling behaviour. I guess to seem more app-like than Web-like but honestly I tend to just find it annoying and unnecessary most of the time.

Paging makes it easy to get to the last page or even to a specific page (not often used but sometimes it is).

I do think it works for Google Reader but you'll note that others like Gmail use traditional paging.

Comment: +1 this sort of flashiness is not needed on this kind of website. It'd just complicate things for little reward other than "ooo"

Answer (score 1):

And... **done!**

[Here](https://stackapps.com/questions/2614/infinite-scrolling-never-click-another-page-number-again) is a UserScript that does exactly that. Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

That would be nice if doesn't slow things down, it's already getting a little busy on the site.