# What are the main competitor sites to Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

What are the main competitor sites to Stack Overflow?
I'm aware of [Experts-Exchange](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Experts-Exchange) and several forum sites that I use for C#, however this question is more about sites that cater for all programming languages just like Stack Overflow and are not generic like Experts-Exchange.

Comment: Like Chuck Norris, SOFUE has no competitors, just innocent bystanders it hadn't decided to demolish yet...

Comment: +1 This question has new-found relevance.

Comment: @faintsignal, indeed.

Comment: If I had more rep here I'd offer a bounty.

Comment: accepted. thanks for reminder @faintsignal

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Programming websites: daniweb, dreamincode, codecall, bytes, devshed, and codingforums off the top of my head.

general Q&A: Yahoo answers (ok for any type of question, not actually good for any)

**Stack Overflow has nothing to worry about.** I know that may not be why you asked the question, but its kind of an overwhelming fact. SO beats the crap out of every other website in terms of rep system, features, organization, traffic, speed, moderation, and questions per day. I've done a lot of comparison, and SO almost always wins in every test.

**[more programming websites](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/387797/good-programming-website-like-stack-overflow/907126#907126)**

Comment: thanks this is an excellent answer.

Comment: Speed, speed, speed! If it gets any faster, the answers will be there before you have finished asking the question. (Hmm, that gives me an idea...)

Comment: I can think of 73 recently quit / on strike mods that might switch to the competition and actively promote their sites.

Comment: The linked question has been deleted. Was it migrated to meta.SO?

Comment: @faintsignal It was deleted as "spam or rude or abusive". It was not. It was a polite, honest question about alternatives. (It's OK to delete it, because this question simply had no place on stack overflow. It's just the *reason* that seems dubious...)

Comment: both answers were good, in the end this one seemed better, content wise.

Answer (score 10):

**[Quora](http://www.quora.com)**

- Category: General Q & A
- Meta discussion: [What can we learn from Quora?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44618/what-can-we-learn-from-quora)

Comment: nice one thanks. I checked the site and one difference is that you can't just be anonymous but must login.

Comment: @AnonymousType You don't have to login to use Quora. See https://www.quora.com/Can-people-view-Quora-without-signing-up/answer/Franck-Dernoncourt?share=1

Comment: yes but then you get only the question and have to search from google. sorry for the delayed reply.