# What are the most useful competitors to the individual StackExchange sites?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange

This question could be useful to have answers to, for two purposes.

1. For users: alternative sites to go to if they don't get a good answer (or any answer) on a StackExchange site.
2. For the owners and fans of the StackExchange sites: to track the competition and see what can be done to make StackExchange better.

Answer (score 2):

Is there any reason you're not asking this on the individual per-site metas? It seems perfectly irrelevant here -- and certainly the individual communities in Minnesota (like, say, Bicycling), would be more interested and able to contribute viable answers than we are here in Washington, D.C (that is, Meta Stack Overflow) ...

Answer (score 0):

**[Quora](http://quora.com/)** (which is an any-topic Q&A site) is a very useful competitor to OnStartups, simply because it has a critical mass of users from the Silicon Valley and entrepreneur community, including some VCs. (See also [What can we learn from Quora?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44618/what-can-we-learn-from-quora))