# Aggregate User Feed Feature

Tags: feature-request, feed

Could we add a feature to that aggregates updates (posted questions, answers) from specified users? Not a *friend list*, but something like a 'wall' for followed individuals?

This would facilitate user interaction in the Q/A loop, which is hardly "social networking." In contrast with comments on the top answer to [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/886/a-friends-list-on-stack-overflow-would-be-nice), I argue that it would only enhance StackOverflow's function as a question and answer forum.

We already have the ability to star a question, so why not a user?

Comment: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/07/code-its-trivial.html

Comment: Besides that, you have given a bunch of reasons why we shouldn't consider your request as a duplicate, but haven't given a single reason why you actually want this.

Comment: I've been meaning to ask this **exact question** for some time.  Why is this question being downvoted?!  This would be a useful feature; I would love to track Eric Lippert's latest answers.  And why is that Jeff-Atwood post relevant?  Rob never said re-creating the entire SO engine would be trivial, just that this particular feature would be.

Comment: Check out this answer too; it looks like other people would like to see this feature too  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44618/what-can-we-learn-from-quora/44629#44629

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't see how they could make this much easier than (or why they would make it *any* different from) [Google Reader](https://www.google.com/accounts/ServiceLogin?service=reader&passive=1209600&continue=http://www.google.com/reader/&followup=http://www.google.com/reader/).  You can add feeds from your browser's address bar (so right from any SE page that has an RSS feed) and read them all in one place.

Comment: @Rob: I forgot Chrome doesn't have that.  In that case you have to use the feed link at the bottom right of a user's profile page.

Comment: I didn't know there was a user feed.  Wow, thanks Bill.  I guess this would be a bit of a superfluous feature.

Comment: For what it's worth, note that [Jeff doesn't think "RSS has a very interesting or useful future."](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106199/make-it-easier-to-find-the-question-feed-icon-link/106214#106214)