# Make it easier to find the Question Feed icon / link

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, questions, user-interface, feed

Question feeds are HUGELY useful, making it possible to organize and track questions of interest. However, the RSS icon and feed link are pretty buried in the UI.

[image: Screenshot]

Personally, I can count on one hand the number of times I've gone past the first question or two of the related questions list, much less down to the bottom of it where the feed link is.

Can the Icon / link be moved to a more visible location on the question page?

My thought would be to move it to one of two places:

- Between the Star and Facebook icons (remove the question feed text link in this case)

or

- The top of the right side-bar, above the tag breakout

I think this would help to make this feature more frequently used.

**EDIT:**

Jeff, in response to your answer.  I admittedly have not taken much stock in the question feeds and have not even looked at them much until today.  I've been looking for a better way to keep track of questions, mainly for finding the duplicates more easily when I know something has already been asked.  I found that today with the RSS feeds.  Pop those into your favorite reader and you instantly have an method for organizing the questions you want to keep track of without requiring further UI changes.

Of course, the argument could be made (and has even been made today) that if there is such a deficiency then a UI feature could be warranted but the same can also be said for searching.  Google is the SE search engine (yeah, even after the relatively recent search improvements), let Google Reader and browser bookmarks be the Question Filing System.

I'd at least request that you keep this in mind when thinking of the RSS feeds and, even if they don't get much more love from the dev team, at least don't discontinue support for them.

Comment: Was this in some way related to this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106188/repost-of-watch-vs-favorite

Comment: Inspired by Chris's comment on Bill's answer to your question.

Comment: Indeed. You beat me to it!

Comment: +1, How about above **Linked**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be brutally honest, we don't think RSS has a very interesting or useful future.

It's available in two places:

1. the `<head>` tag where it can be auto-detected by the browser
2. in the footer.

That's where it will remain for the forseeable future.

Comment: Really? You "don't think RSS has a very interesting or useful future"? Could you elaborate a bit more on why? I use RSS feeds to keep up-to-date on dozens of blogs that I wouldn't read otherwise. I think that it would be just as useful for keeping track of information on the Stack Exchange network, and I doubt that I'm the only one.

Comment: Augh, yer killin me.  Have a look at my edit.  Even if they still don't float your boat, I've stated quite a viable use case for the feeds.  Not really sure what you mean by "we don't think RSS has a very interesting or useful future", whether that means in the context of SE or as a "protocoal".  If as a protocol, then some kind of aggregation is certainly of benefit.

Answer (score 8):

[Jeff may feel that RSS doesn't have "a very interesting or useful future"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106199/move-the-question-feed-icon-link/106214#106214), but he is correct in saying that **RSS feeds on Stack Overflow are (usually) detected by web browsers automatically.** The only reason I didn't notice this before is that Firefox 4 has removed the **Subscribe** button from the address bar. If you're using Firefox 4 (or a more recent version), just customize your toolbar to include the **Subscribe** button.

[image: Subscribe button in the new Firefox toolbar]

You can use this for all sorts of things on Stack Overflow:

- Individual questions
- [Recent questions](https://stackoverflow.com/feeds)
- Any user's activity

Unfortunately, **not every feed is automatically detected properly.** In particular, **you need to manually scroll down to the bottom of the Stack Overflow home page to subscribe to the following feeds** (or just use the links below).

- [featured questions feed](https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/featured)
- [hot questions feed](https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/hot)
- [weekly questions feed](https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/week)
- [monthly questions feed](https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/month)

Hope this helps!