# Follow a question

Tags: feature-request

I've come across a few interesting questions over the last few months on Stack Overflow. They're not necessarily questions I need an answer to, but the questions are nonetheless very interesting, and now I want to know what the answers are.

I don't want to add this question to my favourites because I have my really handy posts in there.

Ideally I would like to have another kind of shortlist to which I can add these posts. I would get notifications just as if it were my own post, without having these as favourites.

What do you think of that? It would be available only for questions, and you would receive notifications just like the author, for new answers and comments on the question (not comments on the answers).

You could browse the posts you're following, as well as stop following them.

The thing is sometimes I come across a semi interesting question and upvote and maybe even comment, but I never hear about it again, because sometimes it's just not interesting enough to remember.

Like I said in the comments, I don't feel like the favourite list is really for this. **I want in-your-face red dot notifications for new answers on brand new interesting questions I find**. The favourites is for that post with an answer that you know you'll need again.

Comment: So you want an extra favourite feature because the existing favourite feature is already in use for something else by you?

Comment: I don't feel like the favourite list is really for this. I want in-your-face red dot notification for new answers on brand new interesting questions I find. The favourites is for that post with an answer you *know* you'll need again.

Comment: I feel it's 2 different usages favourite/follow

Comment: This is a good idea, +1, unfortunately it's too "social", and so will likely be lambasted by the community.

Comment: I would also like to see something like this. My current solution is to just leave the question open in one of my many browser tabs, and check on it every once in a while when I'm cleaning up my open tabs. As you might guess, that's not a very ideal solution :)

Comment: Maybe you're right, but I've got to that point now where I am on here every day and I want to help people out, i don't have many questions of my own and I find a ton of kind of interesting - *hey you know, I wonder how to do that* - questions, I don't really want to bookmark them, and adding to favourites is making that list cluttered.

Comment: In the same ballpark: [Pekka's social features request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106717/does-so-need-social-networking-features-to-improve-the-experience-for-expert-use)  -- it was rated extremely highly by the community, but shot down in the most absurd way by Mr. Atwood.  I really hope the new management takes a more grownup look at things like this going forward.

Comment: @AdamRackis I personally don't really see the need for a feature like this, but I don't at all get your social angle.

Comment: @Bart - signing up for notifications on changes to certain questions seems, *to me*, like the sort of social networking features the community hates.  But I could be wrong.

Comment: @AdamRackis Mwah, as long as it's not following specific users, there's not much of a social factor imho. So I would not hold that against this specific proposal.

Comment: @AdamRackis Just because this is functionality that also happens to be implemented on social networking sites doesn't mean the feature itself is social in nature, because it's not.  Social networking sites also often have authentication systems, but authentication systems aren't social in nature.

Comment: @Servy - that's a fair argument.  This is definitely *less of a* social feature than the Pekka request I linked.

Comment: I agree, I don't think it makes it social, the word follow to our ears just forces an unnecessary association with say Twitter perhaps... This should be totally private, opt-in feature for users say with over 5000 rep or something. Great link by the way, I don't want to follow a user, I just visit their favs and latest answers for that

Comment: I do have a couple of guru users I know, I have them bookmarked, I wouldn't mind having a recommendation system for the questions they recommend.

Comment: @Daniel Why would you need to have 5k rep to use this?  I see no reason for there to be any rep requirement at all.  A 1 rep user can be just as interested in new answers to a good question as anyone else, and it's not like the feature is expensive, costly, or subject to likely abuse in any way.

Comment: Sure, there's no reason for it to be protected.

Comment: +1. I'd like this feature. I feel that follow and favorite are two different scenarios. There is a question I just found interesting and would like to see what would be the correct answer to it so I mark it to follow. Once I learn the answer I un-follow it. With the favorite feature I usually keep these as my favorites for future references.

Comment: Have you tried bookmarks with a sync option?

Comment: *The favourites is for that post with an answer that you know you'll need again.* No, that's what *you* use the favorites feature for. Personally, I use it for posts that I want to check on from time to time.

Comment: I agree but I though a different behaviour. When you found a question interesting and you want to know how it will be end(its answer), you can *follow* it, to get its notification(as you said). But when the question is answered(or finished, indeed), your *follow* will automatically be deleted, and you'll have to fav it. So, that way, answered questions cannot be followed, only favorited.

Comment: +1 for a great proposal.  I wrote a background application to poll my interesting questions.  It was easy to write as a developer's  "immediate gratification convenience app", but has no scalability.  The notion that implementing this feature attracts a "social" context  can be mitigated by making it private or alternatively saying "HEY, the whole thing is social anyway".  Lighten up peeps!

Comment: +1 for follow notifications. Works well on Facebook. Sometimes you just like to watch #giggidy

Comment: @wnn just for the record, "ordinary" diamond mod is not in position to accept or decline feature requests. What we need is Stack Exchange employee (usually a developer or a community manager) to have a look and make a decision. To be honest, it's **very** rare in feature requests but of course it's always worth trying.

Comment: Just made a quick investigation, out of [3,423 feature requests made in 2013-2014, not tag synonym requests or app requests](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfeature-request%5D+closed%3Ano+-%5Bios-app%5D+-%5Bandroid-app%5D+-%5Btag-synonyms%5D+created%3A2013..2014), only [420 got any official response](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfeature-request%5D+closed%3Ano+%5Bstatus-*%5D+-%5Bios-app%5D+-%5Bandroid-app%5D+-%5Btag-synonyms%5D+created%3A2013..2014), one way or the other.

Comment: @ShadowWizard, ahh, thanks for the clarification and research, that's very interesting indeed! Amusingly posting a bounty on the question got the result this post is advocating for. (wooo)

Answer (score 4):

This is definitely a feature I would look forward to have on Stack Overflow.

There is an interim solution, StackApps app called StackStalker (Google Chrome Extension). You can check it out here:

**StackStalker**: [Be Notified When Your Question Is Updated](https://stackapps.com/questions/493/stackstalker-be-notified-when-your-question-is-updated-chrome-extension) (Chrome Extension)

Comment: Isn't it covered by the RSS feed for a question, e.g. https://meta.stackexchange.com/feeds/question/157234 for this very question?

Comment: Illustrated in: *[Make it easier to find the Question Feed icon / link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106199)*

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a great idea. I would like to see this implemented as requested where a user would be able to share the ownership notifications on a question through some sort of follow feature. Perhaps an icon below the star which would indicate follow so you could also see how many users were following that question.

On the other hand, I can see some reasons against this. First, there is the favorites section which does allow you to track questions - it just requires a little more effort on your end to check in on a question. Secondly, it is possible that this would encourage extended discussions on questions in comments and I am not sure that is desired as comments tend to get migrated to chat by mods if they are extended. Perhaps a few more comments and scrubbing of content could be nice though and may encourage more accurate content and editing.

Answer (score 1):

Now that this can of worms is open, and receiving community support, let's consider what a complete implementation would look like. The work to add the two features below I suspect to be only slightly more than the partial implementation above, but should seal this request class for some time.

- Instead of having two types of **Favorites**, which simply the begs the quesiton of why not 3 or 4 or even more, simply allow usrs to create **Named Favorites** by entering a short mnemonic phrase when they select the **Favorites** icon. As an initial guess, I suspect that 9 characters is long enough for creativity to be exercised, without overloading the DB.
- [Optional] For those who find one favorite list sufficient, add a profile setting **Enable Named Favorites** which defaults to **Off**, so only those who desire this feature would see a change to the curent interface.
- In the user profile, users would select which **Named Favorites** lists would receive re-dot notifications.

Have I missed anything?

Comment: This seems like a separate request. Using named favorites is an interesting idea as it would allow some sort of separation of concern to be utilized with regards to marking questions as favorites, perhaps by tag. However, I do not see how that relates to **notifications** which seemed to be the primary point of this question.

Comment: @TravisJ: I see the common element being "a new kind of user-maintained list". Rather than implementing a separate feature with common functionality, extending the existing feature and enabling users to utilize it as they see fit seems more productive in the long run.

Comment: This is perfect - and you'd control which, or any, of your named favorite lists you receive re-dot notifications on, right?

Comment: And no, there's no need for an `Enable Named Favorites` setting.  Just give everyone a default named favorite list, called Favorites, pre-fill everyone's existing favorites, and then let the user do whatever he or she wants.

Comment: @AdamRackis: My reason for the switch is so that users can completely opt out of the feature, including any additional button-clicks needed when adding a favorite.

Comment: There's still no need - just have the option to receive notification updates for specific named favorite lists be off by default, with the user able to opt in as desired.

Comment: @AdamRackis: We disagree; how about we leave detailed design to the SE implementors?

Comment: Unless you propose something with as few moving pieces and complexity as possible, it's unlikely anyone at SE will even consider it.  Boolean flags like that in your profile are, imo, a design smell.  *Without* this your proposal actually would fit seamlessly with the way SE currently works, and could actually be feasible.

Comment: @AdamRackis: Granted. I thought only to minimize the impact on any users who were intent on their user interface not changing; I don't know how much of an issue that really is on SE.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding implementation side of it, I'd like to suggest something inline with already existing notification mechanism for owned answers and questions. Right now the notification icon is red on top, and then on Responses tab on your profile there is a white on blue icon showing a number of them on it. If it's not your question/answer, but something you subscribed to, can be another one, black on grey, to be less distractive, but still give a visual cue.

So you could possibly have two icons, red + grey on top, and blue + grey in responses. Those subscribed responses could be showing greyed out, similar to how questions with non-favorite tags are shown, to quickly weed them out, if you are not particularly interested in them. Also can add a sub-tab under `Responses`, so right now we have `All`, which would list responses to you + responses to Q/A you subscribed to, and also `me/to me/mine` (suggest a better wording), which would list `All` minus your subscriptions (current behavior of `All`).

The new functionality can be disabled by default, and enabled in options by request. You can then leave a hint in `Responses`, such as a question mark `?`, hovering on which displays a note about this option. Something like "Did you know you can subscribe to responses to other questions/answers, not just yours? See this link for more details".