# Why is not there a feature to follow questions?

Tags: feature-request, questions, bookmarks

On *Quora*, there is a feature to follow questions asked, either privately or publicly, so whenever one or more new answers are added, followers get notified. As far as I know, there is no feature like that on *Stack Exchange*. That is annoying me. Sometimes, there are very interesting questions to which equally interesting answers may be written anytime. Sometimes, any question may get one or more great answers even after a long period of time of being asked.

I want to follow questions that interest me, so that if one or more new answers are added, I get notified, even it is years afters the question was first asked. Other people have suggested marking questions as favorite and checking them every once in a while, but I find it a bad idea, and that it will be time-consuming to do so.

The placeholder in *Title* is **"What's your bug, *feature request*, or meta-discussion topic? Be specific."** So, this is my *feature request*. I hope that it will not fall on deaf ears.

Comment: also related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13546/please-allow-me-to-follow-questions

Comment: There is an RSS feed for each question, lower right on a question page (but not if the question is closed, like this one). It is illustrated in *[Make it easier to find the Question Feed icon / link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106199)*.

Comment: For convenience, there is autodetect and a button in Firefox, but you may have to [enable it first](https://superuser.com/questions/261123/in-firefox-4-how-do-i-get-the-rss-feed-button-back/261127#261127).